How to resolve "Refused to frame 'https://localhost:4200/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive" issue?
I'm unable to load an iframe inside the web application. It was working fine till date, and out of the blue I started facing this issue:
In place of the iframe, it says: This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.

the console says:
Refused to frame 'LOCAL_HOST_URL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' 'WALKME_URL'  'COMPANY_URL' 'ANOTHER_LOCAL_HOST_URL' blob: data: 'MICROSOFT_LOGIN_URL' 'KBMAX_URL' 'ONE_ANOTHER_URL' 'ATLASSIAN_URL'".

It is an Angular web application with .NET for the backend.
I tried updating the Content Security Policy (CSP) in project's index.html file to allow framing of 'LOCAL_HOST_URL'.
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' 'WALKME_URL' 'COMPANY_URL' 'ANOTHER_LOCAL_HOST_URL' 'LOCAL_HOST_URL' blob: data: 'MICROSOFT_LOGIN_URL' 'KBMAX_URL' 'ONE_ANOTHER_URL' 'ATLASSIAN_URL' ">
EDIT: I was unable to post the question as it was getting recognized as spam. So I replaced actual URLS with a token like "YOUR_URL_HERE" so it doesn't look like a url at all.

Can you add the HTTP headers for the iframe response?

The headers Content-Security-Policy takes precedence over the <meta> value. You'd need to update the back-end.

@tomasdev when you say i need to update the backend, what do you mean by that? could you please explain?
